# Creating Zones according to the x,y axis in 2D charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I tried creating zones for displaying different colored points for particular zone. I can create zones either on the basis of values of y-axis or x-axis. I tried to create zones on the basis of x-axis and y-axis but highchart picks only latest one for creating zones. Here is the example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/62xmLdhL/

Sample code:

```
series: [{
            data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],           
            zoneAxis:'y',
            zones: [
            {
                value: -5,
                color: '#ddd'
            },
                {
                value: 0,
                color: '#eee'
            },
            {
                value: 10,
                color: '#7cb5ec'
            }, 
            {
                value: 20,
                color: '#000'
            }],
//if you uncomment the below code you will see that zones will be created according to the x-axis            
           /* zoneAxis:'x',
            zones: [
            {
                value: 3,
                color: '#ddd'
            },
            {
                value: 7,
                color: '#7cb5ec'
            }, 
            {
                value: 11,
                color: '#000'
            }]*/
        }]
```

I want to make zones on the basis of x,y coordinate. How can we achieve this by Highcharts.

Comment: Only one zoneAxis per series is supported. You can create an idea on the [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general).